# How do I use the Enumerable mixin in my presenter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enumerable

I've got a presenter which I would like to make the each_with_index method available in. I've added `include Enumerable` in my base presenter however, I'm still getting a no method error. My current code is below:

### index.erb

```
<% @bids.each_with_index do |bid, index| %>
  <% present bid do |bid_presenter| %>
     <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns <%= bid_presenter.last_column %>"></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

### bid_presenter.rb

```
class BidPresenter < BasePresenter      
    presents :bid

    def last_column
        if index == bid.size - 1
            'end'
        end
    end
end
```

### base_presenter.rb

```
class BasePresenter
  include Enumerable
    def initialize(object, template)
        @object = object
        @template = template
    end

private

    def self.presents(name)
        define_method(name) do
            @object
        end
    end

    # h method returns the template object
    def h
        @template
    end

    # if h is missing fallback to template
    def method_missing(*args, &block)
        @template.send(*args, &block)
    end
end
```

### bids_controller.erb

```
  # GET /bids
  # GET /bids.json
  def index
    @bids = current_user.bids
  end
```

Comment: Good question, and unfortunately I'm not sure how to use the `each_with_index` method inside a presenter..however, you can get around it with a while loop. `while i < @binds.length`...Inside the loop you would have the value of `i` and I would just increment i by 1 at the end of the loop. `i += 1`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JustinLicata do you know if I am able to do this inside my bid_presenter.rb? I can already achieve this using the above method inside my loop. Cheers

Comment: Yep I just tested it in a presenter. That being said, someone may answer with how to use `each_with_index` inside your presenter :)

Comment: Thanks @JustinLicata could you provide the example code as an answer? Even though it doesn't directly answer the question it provides others with alternative options for achieving the same thing. Thanks :)

Comment: Come to think of it, I would only use instance methods in the presenters. I would keep the `each_with_index` in the view.

Comment: Could you paste the entirety of the error? And maybe even a couple lines of the stacktrace?

Comment: How do you create `@bids`?

Comment: @cdmwebs in my controller or model?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor yeah, just curious. I've got a working example, but I'm curious where you're creating the bids to be presented.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor on second look, I'm not sure delegating is possible without having some kind of BidsPresenter as well. What if you just pass index to the last_column method instead?

Comment: @cdmwebs I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I have a BidPresenter? Sure, how would I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

You are forwarding all not explicitly implemented methods to `@template`. Whatever `@template` is doesn't seem to properly implement `each`. You need to make `@template` respond properly to `each`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea on how to achieve that?